# Extract Data from MongoDBList

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

How can I get a `List(String)` from this `MongoDBList`?

```
val a: MongoDBList = ... // equal to [ { "id" : "0001"} , { "id" : "0017"}]
```

Desired result: `List("0001", "0017")`

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDBList](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.2/scaladoc/com/mongodb/casbah/commons/MongoDBList.html) extends [scala.collection.mutable.LinearSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinearSeq) so you should be able to to use toList

```
val bld = MongoDBList.newBuilder

bld += MongoDBObject("id" -> "0001")
bld += MongoDBObject("id" -> "0017")

val a = bld.result

val l = for( o <- a.toList )
  yield JSON.parse(o.toString).asInstanceOf[DBObject].get("id")

println(l)

//output
//List(0001, 0017)
```

Comment: Hi David - when I try that, I get `List({ "id" : "0001"}, { "id" : "0017"})`. After getting this result, I suppose I need to convert each item to a `JsValue`, and then parse via `val idVal = (listElementJson \ "id").asOpt[String]`?

Comment: I didn't quite follow what you were asking, answer is updated to reflect actual question

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
val bld = MongoDBList.newBuilder

bld += MongoDBObject("id" -> "0001")
bld += MongoDBObject("id" -> "0017")

val a = bld.result

a.map(x=> x.asInstanceOf[DBObject].getAs[String]("id").get)
// or to avoid nonexitence emelents
a.flatMap(x=> x.asInstanceOf[DBObject].getAs[String]("id"))
```

I don't like asInstanceOf here if you have

```
{ "data" : [ { "id" : "0001"} , { "id" : "0017"}] }
```

casbash can serialize Seq for you

```
val a2 = MongoDBObject( "data" -> a )
a2.getAs[Seq[DBObject]]("aa").get.map { x => x.getAs[String]("id").get}
```